# Meaning of the layoutopt output

Tags: android, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I used the `layoutopt` to enhance the layouts and to identify inefficiencies in them. I get the following message ,

```
F:\Trunk\AndroidApp\Pixecon\res\layout-land\take_photo.xml
182:215 This RelativeLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless
```

The layout file `take_photo.xm`l is as follows

```
  <RelativeLayout                            //     line 179
   android:id="@+id/rview4"                  //     line 180
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"        //     line 181
   android:layout_height="162dp"  >          //     line 182

       <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"        
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"                         
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" android:layout_width="160dip"/>

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/coverFlowBlock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListView01" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <ImageView android:id="@+id/spacer3"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_height="5dp" 
           android:src="@drawable/spacer"    />            

           <ImageView android:id="@+id/spacer2"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="5dp" 
           android:src="@drawable/spacer"    ></ImageView>

           <com.pixecon.CoverFlow android:id="@+id/coverFlow"                   
           android:layout_width="310dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/spacer2"
           android:layout_above="@+id/spacer3"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"  /> 

        </RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>                               // line 215
```

Output of `layoutopt` says `RelativeLayout` is possibly useless, so should I need to remove this Relative layout?
I am confused what it exactly means, so please anyone help me out to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Read this here: [Layout optimization](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-tools-layout-optimization/)

Such an error output is a result of unused or abandoned instructions
Advice: try to minimize your xml as much as possible leaving only the most important parts. This is very common issue with relatively big xml files, sometimes you just get lost and move things around, so it results in a lot of unused code